# Elliptic curve addition - how to add point coordinates from a file in Python

Tags: python, bitcoin, ecdsa

i'm just a tech newbie learning how ec cryptography works and stumbled into a problem with my python code

i'm testing basic elliptic curve operations like adding points, multiple by G etc, let's say i have

```
Ax = 0xbc46aa75e5948daa08123b36f2080d234aac274bf62fca8f9eb0aadf829c744a
Ay = 0xe5f28c3a044b1cac54a9b4bf719f02dfae93a0bae73832301e786104f43255a5
A = (Ax,Ay)

f = open('B-coordinates.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()     
f.close()     
print (data)            
B = 'data'
```

there B-coordinates.txt contains lines like (0xe7e6bd3424a1e92abb45846c82d570f0596850661d1c952f9fe3564567d9b9e8,0x59c9e0bba945e45f40c0aa58379a3cb6a5a2283993e90c58654af4920e37f5)

then i perform basic point addition A+B add(A,B)

so because of B = 'data' i obviously have this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

and if i add int(data) >

```
Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: because letters in input (i.e. in points coordinates).
```

so my question is, please can someone knowledgeable in python and elliptic curve calculations tell me how to add the coordinates of a point so as to bypass these int problems when extracting lines from a file into .py? I will be very grateful for the answer! I've been trying to figure out how to do it right for many hours now, and maybe just goofing off, but please I'll appreciate any hints

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont want to set B equal to 'data' (as a string) but instead to data (as the variable)

replace `B = 'data'` with `B = data` in the last row

Your data seems to be a tuple of hex-strings.
Use int(hex_string, 16) to convert them (since hex is base 16 not 10)

EDIT based on comment:

Assuming your file looks like this:
[image]

```
with open("B-coordinates.txt", "r") as file:
    raw = file.read()

data = [tuple(int(hex_str, 16) for hex_str in item[1:-1].split(",")) for item in raw.split("\n")]
```

You can then get the first Bx, By like this:

```
Bx, By = data[0]
```

Comment: hello bitflip, thanks for answer. already tried it but I keep getting the same error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'. wonder that 'wrapper' i need to use to correct result.

Comment: Did you try something like that?

`for hex_string in data[1:-1].split(','):
    print(int(hex_string, 16))`

Comment: thanks! tried it and get the following error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7)\n(0x754e3239f325570cdbbf4a87deee8a66b7f2b33479d468fbc1a50743bf56cc18'

not sure what i do wrong

Comment: Didnt know you have a new line \n in your data.
Can you try to do your calculation with
int("0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7", 16)

and tell me if it gives you the correct result?

Comment: Note that the visual representation will be different. But the results should be the same.

Comment: bitflip, sorry for delay, trying to figure out how to do it with tuple(Bx,By). 

if i do int("0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7", 16) > this gives me the right result

Comment: but if i do int("data", 16) >> invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'data' again

Comment: Try it with one example from your file first. So copy the tuple out of it and apply int. We can deal with the correct parsing later

Comment: "data" is wrong in any case as it creates a new string "data" that has nothing to do with your input

Comment: tried to divide them into Bx,By with 2 dif files and apply int separately, but again

x = 'By.txt'
f = open(x, "r")
for line in f:
    data = (int("line", 16))
    print(data)
f.close()
...

there line - just 0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7
but also ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'line'

but int("0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7", 16) gives me the right res, but its value not from a file, just directly my input

Comment: (int(line, 16))

Comment: sorry for another delay, it (int(line,16)) works! but only if I split Bx and By into two separate files. tried to do a B=(Bx,By) but without success

Comment: I've made an edit to my post to reflect your input.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed help, really appreciate that! there was also a problem with using rstrip in relation to 'tuple' to correctly perform elliptic point addition. you provided a cool solution! I hope it will help someone else also

Answer (score 0):

You can load `B` from `B-coordinates.txt` by [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)uating its content as Python code:

```
B = eval(data)
```

As the code above leads to [arbitrary code execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) if you don't trust `B-coordinates.txt` content. If so, parse the hexadecimal [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) manually:

```
B = tuple([int(z, 16) for z in data[1:-1].split(',')])
```

Then to sum `A` and `B` in a pairwise manner using native Python 3 and keep a tuple, you can proceed as follows by summing unpacked coordinates ([`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)) for both tuples:

```
print(tuple([a + b for (a, b) in zip(A, B)]))
```

UPDATE:

Assume `B-coordinates.txt` looks like the following as described by OP author comment:

```
(0x1257e93a78a5b7d8fe0cf28ff1d8822350c778ac8a30e57d2acfc4d5fb8c192,0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7)
(0x754e3239f325570cdbbf4a87deee8a66b7f2b33479d468fbc1a50743bf56cc18,0x673fb86e5bda30fb3cd0ed304ea49a023ee33d0197a695d0c5d98093c536683)
...
```

You can load the `B`s from this file by doing:

```
f = open('B-coordinates.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
Bs = [eval(line) for line in lines]
```

As described above to avoid arbitrary code execution, use the following:

```
Bs = [tuple([int(z, 16) for z in line[1:-1].split(',')]) for line in lines]
```

That way you can use for instance the first `B` pair, by using `Bs[0]`, defined by the first line of `B-coordinates.txt` that is:

```
(0x1257e93a78a5b7d8fe0cf28ff1d8822350c778ac8a30e57d2acfc4d5fb8c192,0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7)
```

Comment: thanks for valuable advise! tried it and get the following error - 

 invalid literal for int() with base 16

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my input. maybe I should split Bx and By into two separate files?

Comment: get the following error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7)\n(0x754e3239f325570cdbbf4a87deee8a66b7f2b33479d468fbc1a50743bf56cc18'

not sure what i do wrong

Comment: In your question it seems that you wanted to say that `B-coordinates.txt` contains exactly `(0xe7e6bd3424a1e92abb45846c82d570f0596850661d1c952f9fe3564567d9b9e8,0x59c9e0bba945e45f40c0aa58379a3cb6a5a2283993e90c58654af4920e37f5)`. As you just commented, it doesn't seem to be the case. May you give exactly `B-coordinates.txt` content?

Comment: sure thing, just lines like (Bx,By) and each new (Bx,By) starts with a new line. 

(0x1257e93a78a5b7d8fe0cf28ff1d8822350c778ac8a30e57d2acfc4d5fb8c192,0x1124ec11c77d356e042dad154e1116eda7cc69244f295166b54e3d341904a1a7)
(0x754e3239f325570cdbbf4a87deee8a66b7f2b33479d468fbc1a50743bf56cc18,0x673fb86e5bda30fb3cd0ed304ea49a023ee33d0197a695d0c5d98093c536683)
(0x108443b948d1553584a271333f7fbd043c4d66a91706edecbf07f6894c04f299,0x4e7b5daba34fbcf9f055520d4db8c49fd60282d32adfca555b04403db9581a9f)

Comment: [I updated accordingly my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73873798/revisions).

Comment: thank you for the detailed answers, I appreciate it very much! i tried this

```
f = open('B-coordinates.txt', 'r')

lines = f.read().splitlines()

f.close()

Bs = [eval(line) for line in lines]

Bs = [tuple([int(z, 16) for z in line[1:-1].split(',')]) for line in lines]

print(Bs)
```

but I get the following error

```
  Bs = [eval(line) for line in lines]

  File "<string>", line 0
    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Note that you have to choose one of `Bs` declaration, not both. With your code (so the arbitrary code execution safe declaration of `Bs`) it works fine on my side by `print`ing: `[(518559790775991926153431284348924991691752894319091408626305042091127390610, 7754554211713140270585379622151031431183921268920287121212618482407411327399), (53058764004935428650100139287376587679652978405430403380587712871864611556376, 2918800479109537269737873642942211407706668016660669097675760428828773803651)]`

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed help, really appreciate that! there was also a problem with using rstrip in relation to 'tuple' to correctly perform elliptic point addition. you provided a cool solution! I hope it will help someone else also